# My CSS file errors out no matter what I try

Tags: html, css

My CSS file will not work and I have tried everything. They are both in the same "templates" directory in the app titled "bake".

Using a simple example that doesn't work, here's my HTML head and the code I'm trying to change:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>DataBake</title>
</head>
<body>
     <th style="text-align:right"> <h5 id="green">Username:</h5></th>
     <p id="test">If you're new to DataBake please <a href="registration">register</a> here.</p>
</body>
```

Here is my CSS file:

```
@charset "UTF-8";

#green{
    color: green;
}
h5{
    color: green;
}
#test{
    color: red;
}
```

The CSS works when neither the HTML nor the CSS are in directories and they are the only two files I'm working with. But other than that, I have putting the css file in a separate directory. I have tried changing the link to the 'style.css' to using relative and absolute paths.

When I follow the link from the HTML , it takes me right to the CSS file. When I load the css file independently, it loads fine.

- Both files are encoded to UTF-8.
- I have cleared my cache and history and reloaded countless times.
- I have moved the order between it and my bootstrap link around.
- I have used different browsers.
- I have checked for typos or little mistakes.
- My coding teacher couldn't figure it out either.

Can someone help me figure out why it is not working?

**UPDATE**
When I put the absolute path into my browser, it works perfectly, but the relative path through my localhost turns up a 404 error for the css stylesheet.

**FOUND THE ANSWER**
I needed to incorporate {% load static %} into the header, and turn the href of the stylesheet link to "{% static 'css/style.css' %}". Couldn't be happier to finally have this solved.

Comment: Try deleting the dot in front of style path..

Comment: You mention `app`, this could be me caught on semantics, but are you loading the HTML file directly in your browser or is it being loaded through something else?

Comment: Try removing `@charset "UTF-8";`

Comment: Can you give us a bit more information about the problem itself? For example, how are you checking if the file is being loaded? Are the Bootstrap styles overriding your styles?  Unlikely as `#test` isn't a used in Bootstrap, but something to confirm just incase :) If you use the full path - e.g. `http://whatever` or `file:///C:\....` - does that work? It's difficult to help when we cannot recreate the problem so the more info you can give us the better :)

Comment: @MiloshN. I tried it, no success.

Comment: @imvain2 I believe I'm loading it directly in my browser? I'm just using my local host. I hope I'm answering your question correctly.

Comment: @JonNezbit I started it that way, it didn't work then either.

Comment: @FluffyKitten After my page loads, I'm inspecting the elements. Console is telling me about the 404 error, and the Network / CSS tabs also tell me "Failed to load response data". I've added more info to the OP, so I hope that helps. Let me try just commenting out Bootstrap and using the full path.

Comment: @FluffyKitten Using the file:///... path worked! So then why isn't my localhost:8000 working?

Comment: If it is loading with the absolute path then it mustn't be finding it with the relative path... no idea why though, sorry!

Comment: @FluffyKitten So aggravating. Thanks for your help, though.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: There are many things that in my opinion could have been written better when drafting this question.

It's very difficult to help you with your problem when there's so little shared. You should at least share some code where you're actually using the styling. Time to time there's just some typos you end up missing and extra pair of eyes might pick them up.

The one thing that comes to mind that you could try is adding space between the css selector and the bracket. So not `#green{` but rather `#green {`.

I'm suggesting this just because few months ago I agonized with some styles that did not show up in my React project where I was using *css-modules*. It took embarrassingly long time until I noticed that the class giving me grief was written without the space before bracket and it just didn't compile correctly.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I didn't add enough information. I'm definitely a new coder. Let me add a space there and here are those lines of code in the body:

Comment: Even with the spaces added, it's still getting a 404 error.

Comment: @JJHawkins Just FYI, you don't usually need a space between  the class/id and `{` - it might be needed for some compilers but not generally, in case you think you have to change all you code :) Also, please update your question with any additional info so everyone sees it. Also include answers to the questions I asked in my comment.

Comment: I've added the edits to the OP. And @FluffyKitten thank you so much. I completely bypassed the first couple of comments.

Answer (score -2):

try and remove bootstrap (or add it before you include your file). What kind of server are you using ? maybe it is serving your css file as TXT/html (look at it on the server response, which would mean your browser may not accept it as a stylesheet)

Comment: My browser is accepting it as a stylesheet, I've inspected the elements and all that. :/

Comment: you have inspected the elements and it is not applied. Do you mean you find the rules in your elements (in this case i strongly recommand adding your css link AFTER bootstrap because maybe your rules are overwriten by it). What i was talking about was the http response's header (that you can find in the networking tab in your developpement tools). Look at the one corresponding to the request of your stylesheet file as it may not be applied if the `Content-type` is not `text/css` and therefore it is not accepting it.

Comment: I've tried the link before and after bootstrap. I looked under the network tab and it's registering as a stylesheet, its status is just 404.

Answer (score -3):

You have to put 1 more dot before ./

I hope it would work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style.css">
```

Comment: OP said the files are in the same directory, `../` goes up one directory.

Comment: A single dot  `./`means the *same* directory so there is nothing wrong with that

Comment: I've tried two dots to leave the directory and a single dot to stay in, neither have worked. :/

Answer (score -3):

**EDIT**: I never said that the problem was the dot anyway. The OP should share the entire CSS file together with more information so we could help find the answer.

I've never seen a reference to a path using a dot like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
```

You should ask yourself if the file is in the same directory as the file referencing it? above? below?

- Starting with “/” returns to the root directory and starts there
- Starting with “../” moves one directory backwards and starts there
- Starting with “../../” moves two directories backwards and starts there

Other than that, is difficult to understand the issue without more details, many things can cause this problem.

Comment: `./` is a valid path. It means the current working directory. Please edit your answer to explain how the information you have given can help the OP to solve their problem. They have already stated they are in the same directory, so it is unclear how telling them to move back directories could help.

Comment: Yeah and I've tried every iteration of these suggestions already, too. :/